# Can a parent kick out their underage kid's kids?

Tags: family-law, children, parental-rights

Say you have a 14 year old daughter that has recently birthed a child. Obviously, you cannot kick your own kid out, but what about the kid's kid?

Comment: Where? The law is almost never the same in all places.

Comment: Just a note on the "obvious" part - even when something is illegal, it doesn't mean its impossible. Additionally, even if one successfully uses legality to prevent something happening, sometimes the situation is irreparably damaged anyway. Let's say the 14yo's parent wants to kick out the baby due to noise or something, and the 14yo uses the law to prevent it... do you really think everything is still going to be hunky dory in that living situation? Likely not...

Answer (score 25):

[north-carolina](/questions/tagged/north-carolina)

A parent is responsible for supporting their minor child, therefore they cannot "kick out" their child (they can arrange for someone else to take care of the child but they are financially responsible for this arrangement). This is true even if the parent is a minor. In that case, the grandparents and the parent (who is herself a minor child) are both responsible for the grandchild. We can turn to [NCGS § 50-13.4(b)](https://www.ncleg.net/enactedlegislation/statutes/html/bysection/chapter_50/gs_50-13.4.html) which states the hierarchy of responsibilities:

> In the absence of pleading and proof that the circumstances otherwise
> warrant, parents of a minor, unemancipated child who is the custodial
> or noncustodial parent of a child shall share this primary liability
> for their grandchild's support with the minor parent, the court
> determining the proper share, until the minor parent reaches the age
> of 18 or becomes emancipated. If both the parents of the child
> requiring support were unemancipated minors at the time of the child's
> conception, *the parents of both minor parents share primary liability
> for their grandchild's support until both minor parents reach the age
> of 18 or become emancipated*.

The details could be different in another jurisdiction.

Comment: It seems surprising that a jurisdiction covers this specifically, but here it is.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica teenage pregnancy is a common enough thing, and always has been, that I'd be shocked by jurisdictions that haven't codified the situation in one way or another.

Comment: You can vacate your responsibilities as parent. It is called adoption or foster care. Nobody is forced to be a parent. If you cannot reasonably take care of a child then putting the kid in foster care is the responsible thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

[uk](/questions/tagged/uk)

> Obviously, you cannot kick your own kid out

Not at all "obviously".  Youth homelessness is absolutely a thing, and a major cause is a breakdown of the relationship between the child and parents.  Sometimes this is the child actively running away, sometimes it's the parents actively preventing the child going home.

In the UK, [local government are responsible for children's care](https://www.local.gov.uk/topics/children-and-young-people/childrens-social-care).  There are separate schemes for children under the age of 16 (who cannot legally live on their own) and children between 16 and 18 (who can).  In theory, local government has a duty of care to all children living in that geographical area which supersedes parental responsibility.  Services such as fostering exist to provide care for children who, for whatever reason, cannot live with their parents.

In practise, these schemes have been chronically under-funded under the Conservative Party's [austerity programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_government_austerity_programme) since they took office in 2010, resulting in significant harm ([sometimes fatally](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-cambridgeshire-60302523)) to many children, due simply to the fact that the resources do not exist to properly check on at-risk children.  It may be practically hard for children to access services, and charities such as [Centrepoint](https://centrepoint.org.uk/) are often required to provide temporary support and help young people to access the services they are entitled to.  Still, these services do exist though, and children have a legal right to them.

Comment: So is it legal or not to kick out your own child and/or grandchildren?

Comment: @theonlygusti I bet you cannot shed *responsibility* in most jurisdictions but the law cannot enforce what is sometimes impossible: Living under the same roof. (Granted, the law sometimes criminalizes the unavoidable -- drug consumption by addicts comes to mind -- but I think it is rather rare.)

Comment: -1 This is relevant information, but in no way answers the question asked. It does not say whether it is or is not legal, under UK, law, for a parent to "kick out" a minor child or  grand-child whose parent is a minor child of the parent. It merely says that this in fact happens. But of course many unlawful things happen frequently..

Comment: @Pewter, the law could impose a financial obligation on a parent to support the parent's minor child, and in many places it does just that.

Comment: @theonlygusti you can relieve yourself of parental rights by putting your child in foster care / adoption. Nobody is forced to be a parent.